# Reading a JSON file from Ruby (on Mac OS X)

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm not a Ruby coder, but I do need to read a Json file and access to nodes using such a language.

I did my homework, but I'm not able to finish them because of my lack of knowledge I hope you can compensate.

Let's start with my sample Json file.

```
{
"app": [{
  "name":"test", 
  "ip_address": "172.90.90.90"
}],
"mysql": [{
  "server_password": "root",
  "dbName":"dbname"
}],
"phpmyadmin": [{
  "app_username": "root",
  "app_password": "root"
}]
}
```

And this is the little code fragment I put together to read the file.

```
require 'json'
data = JSON.parse(File.read("data.json"))
```

Now, as long as I do something like

```
print data[0]
```

or

```
print data["app"]
```

everything is fine, but if I try to access the subnode "app"."name" no matter the format or the parenthesis I sue, I always get a system exception. I was expecting as the most reasonable way to do this something like data["app"]["name"] but it is clearly not the case.

I'm testing this using ruby compiler on a Mac Os X which, and Ruby version should be the latest as far as I can understand (ruby 2.0.0p247)

Can you please help me out?
Thanks and have an happy new year start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample data, `app` contains an Array, so you need to access it as such:

```
data["app"][0]["name"]
```

Comment: Ouch ... I did try this too, but I didn't realise it this work even at that time I tested. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because `data["app"]` is an array:

```
1.9.3p484 :001 > require 'json'
 => true 

1.9.3p484 :002 > data = JSON.parse(File.read("/Users/example/Desktop/json.json"))
 => {"app"=>[{"name"=>"test", "ip_address"=>"172.90.90.90"}], "mysql"=>[{"server_password"=>"root", "dbName"=>"dbname"}], "phpmyadmin"=>[{"app_username"=>"root", "app_password"=>"root"}]} 

1.9.3p484 :003 > print data["app"]
[{"name"=>"test", "ip_address"=>"172.90.90.90"}]
```

If you do `data["app"].first["name"]`, you'll get what you want:

```
1.9.3p484 :004 > print data["app"].first["name"]
test
```

Comment: Thanks. What that first stand for? The first array in the set?
Should I assume next will eventually read any following array item in "app" and last will read the latter if any (or different from first)?

Comment: `first` grabs the first element of the array, which in this case is a hash.

Comment: so next and last don't exist?

Comment: `first` is the same as `[0]`, and `last` is the same as `[-1]`. In your data, `first` and `last` would return the same thing since the array only contains one object.